# What is the standard solution to get body class at IE8 and other browsers with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, document-body

I need to get body class at internet explorer 8 and lower, i'm using the javascript classList method but it seems that it's not working on old IE browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=classList), is there any standard solution for new browser and the oldest one?

```
var b = document.body;
// check body class
if (!b.classList.contains('ie-8')) {
    b.classList.add('ie-block');
    // removing DOM main container
    b.removeChild('mainContainer');
}
```

Thx for help.

Comment: there is a nice way to this by https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

Answer (score 1):

You can **use the standard `.className` property**, which contains a space-separated list of the classes.

Also there's an error in your code: the line `b.removeChild('mainContainer');` is wrong: **the `removeChild` method takes an `Element` as argument**, and you are giving a string to it instead. You should first **get that element** (which I suppose is the element with `id="mainContainer"`, **and then remove it** properly.

Stated the above, you can then **check if the body's `className` contains the desired class and behave consequently**, here's a working example:

```
var b = document.body;

if (~(" "+b.className+" ").indexOf(" ie-8 ")) {
    b.className += " ie-block";
    b.removeChild(document.getElementById("mainContainer"));
}
```

**Additional notes:**

- I'm adding those spaces to the `className` because classNames do not usually begin/end with a space, but they separate classes with spaces, so you'll need to check for `" ie-8 "` (with leading spaces), because matching it without spaces can result in a wrong identification (e.g. a class like `"some-ie-8-thing"` would match).
- I'm using `~(...).indexOf` because the `~` operator will return `0` (which is `false`) only if the number returned by `indexOf` is `-1`, which means that the espression will evaluate to true only if the string contains the given substring.
- I am also adding a space at the beginning in `" ie-block"` because of classes being separated with spaces.